# Methods of summary() function

Tags: r, methods, polymorphism

I'm using `summary()` on output of `mle(stats4)` function, its output belongs to class `mle`. I would like to find out how `summary()` estimates standard deviation of coefficient returned by `mle(stats4)`, but I do not see `summary.mle` in list printed by `methods(summary)`, why can't I find `summary.mle()` function ?

(I guess the proper function is `summary.mlm()`, but I'm not sure that and don't know why it would be `mlm`, instead of `mle`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown in

```
>library(stats4)
>showMethods("summary")
Function: summary (package base)
object="ANY"
object="mle"
```

The `summary` is interpreted in the `S4` way. I don't know how to check the code in R directly, so I search the source of `stats4` directly for you.

In `stats4/R/mle.R`, there is:

```
setMethod("summary", "mle", function(object, ...){
    cmat <- cbind(Estimate = object@coef,
                  `Std. Error` = sqrt(diag(object@vcov)))
    m2logL <- 2*object@min
    new("summary.mle", call = object@call, coef = cmat, m2logL = m2logL)
})
```

So it creates a `S4` object `summary.mle`. And I guess you could trace the code by yourself now.

Answer (score 3):

It's actually what summary.mle would be if it were an S3 method. S3 methods get created and then dispatched using the `generic_function_name.class_of_first_argument` mechanism whereas S4 methods are dispatched on the basis of their argument "signature" which allows consideration of second and later arguments. This is how to get `showMethods` to display the code that is called when an S4-method is called. This is an instance where only the first argument is used as the signature. You can choose any of the object signatures that appear in the abbreviated output to specify the `classes`-agument, and it is the `includeDefs` flag that prompts display of the code:

```
showMethods("summary",classes="mle", includeDefs=TRUE)
#---(output to console)----
Function: summary (package base)
object="mle"
function (object, ...) 
{
    cmat <- cbind(Estimate = object@coef, `Std. Error` = sqrt(diag(object@vcov)))
    m2logL <- 2 * object@min
    new("summary.mle", call = object@call, coef = cmat, m2logL = m2logL)
}
```